# How to simulate props in an component for React unit test with Enzyme and Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jasmine, enzyme

```
var data = {aList: ['1','2']};    
describe('react', function() {
    it('has a class name', function() {
        expect(shallow(<myComp
          aList={data.aList}/>).is('.comp-something')).toBe(true);
      });
    });
```

I try to pass values into the component, but seems this is wrong way to do it.

I am using `enzyme`, `jsdom`, `jasmine`, `gulp` for implementing unit test.

Is there some other way to do this properly? Per my understanding, `shallow` is enough as `myComp` is just a static component without any life cycle function involved.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
describe('react', function() {
  it('has a class name', function() {
    expect(shallow(<myComp
          aList={data.aList}/>).find('.comp-something').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that, it is an issue with `jsdom` incompatibility with `node v0.12`. So it will not run properly, so that's why enzyme was acting up! as well as `is` is not a syntax for jasmine.

Thanks